# How to proxy with apache site from same domain but another port as a subfolder?

Tags: apache, proxy, configuration

So I have a problem - I have my main site on apache web server on debian on port `80`; I develop a web server (in some C++ or C#) and it currently runs on port `6666`. But some people are living under firewalls and can access only port `80`. I wonder if it is possible via apache map all requests to say `mysite.com:80/6666/url` as if they were to `mysite.com:6666/url`, not map via redirection, but really make apache stream content from my site to user as if it were in some folder?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a reverse proxy via [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). The Apache Httpd configuration would be along these lines:

```
    ProxyPass /6666/ http://localhost:6666/
    <Location /6666/>
            ProxyPassReverse /6666/
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good answer on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/104882/25764)

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6666 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80`

> This assumes you're not routing traffic for an entire network through
>   this box and that if you were there's no expectation that traffic
>   destined for other hosts will be on that port

Update

In case you mess up your iptables, [here is a great article on flushing the tables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html) and getting back to normal :)

Comment: this seems like it would rout users to the entire port 80 - not emulate a folder under it...